We should change the 'review request' close reason to include products
The question that inspired this: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38871/i-want-to-make-investment-in-btc-mining-machine
It's being closed for this reason:

Questions seeking service reviews are off-topic because they tend to attract subjective, low-quality, and spam answers. On the other hand, services in the Bitcoin space are still evolving rapidly which often renders answers outdated quickly. For more information see this meta-discussion.

This question shows a common issue with this close reason: it is frequently used for closing product recommendation requests too.
We should change this to read:

Questions seeking product or service reviews are off-topic because they tend to attract subjective, low-quality, and spam answers. On the other hand, offerings in the Bitcoin space are still evolving rapidly which often renders answers outdated quickly. For more information see this meta-discussion.

(Changes: 'service reviews' -> 'product or service reviews' and 'services' -> 'offerings')
Thoughts?

Looks good to me.

Okay, it's done.
